# Recyclerview tools:listitem= not work on androidx Api version 30

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, sdk

so I make Recyclerview on my `Android studio version 3.6.3` and I use `tools:listitem=` for show my Recyclerview layout and when I run my emulator, does not appear at the design result, I use android API version 30, and android studio version 3.6.3, I use Kotlin programing language to create my Recyclerview.

this is my main_activity.xml :

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:listitem="@layout/example_item"/>
```

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

this is my example_item.xml :

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/abdulhalim" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image_view"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_view"
        android:text="Line 1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_view"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image_view"
        android:text="Line 2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

this is my MainAcitivity.kt :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


}
```

}

this is the result of when I add     `tools:listitem=`[image] add

Answer (score 0):

Change your parent layout to `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:listitem="@layout/example_item"/>
       </LinearLayout>
```